# Using python Beautiful Soup on a website, keep getting this error: urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Here's the code I'm using to get Nike's clothing data.

```
import urllib.request

#Base url for website
url = 'http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pw/mens-clothing/1mdZ7pu?ipp=120'

# A lot of sites don't like the user agents of Python 3, so I specify one here
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
html = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
```

And then the error looks like this:
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

How can I open and parse this HTML page?

Comment: `html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()`  works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or try `selenium` webdriver.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pw/mens-clothing/1mdZ7pu?ipp=120'
browser.get(url)
source = browser.page_source
soup = bs(source, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

This worked for me, just a newbie though :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import urllib.request

class AppURLopener(urllib.request.FancyURLopener):
    version = "Mozilla/5.0"

opener = AppURLopener()
response = opener.open('http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pw/mens-clothing/1mdZ7pu?ipp=120')
print(response.read())
```

AppURLopener (which inherits from the .request.FancyURLopener class) offers some nice tools to mimic a browser and therefore bypass the 403: Forbidden errors.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could try `requests`.

```
>>> import requests
>>> page = requests.get('http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pw/mens-clothing/1mdZ7pu?ipp=120').content
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `User-Agent`. This website blocks the specified `User-Agent` but works fine without specifying any `User-Agent` in the header.

```
import urllib.request

#Base url for website
url = 'http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pw/mens-clothing/1mdZ7pu?ipp=120'

# A lot of sites don't like the user agents of Python 3, so I specify one here
req = urllib.request.Request(url)
html = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
print(html)
```

But if you want to add the header anyway I would recommend you to use `requests`. First install the package via `pip` using - `pip install requests`.

```
import requests

#Base url for website
url = 'http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pw/mens-clothing/1mdZ7pu?ipp=120'

# A lot of sites don't like the user agents of Python 3, so I specify one here
html = requests.get(url, headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
print(html.text)
```

For details documentation about `requests` see this [page](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @AbhikNag You're welcome. By the way, why don't you accept an answer if the answers helped.